# GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false ; The module has not been deployed

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to create a web application when I create session beans form it shows me the error:

GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\realestateTest\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1045: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.

Netbeans version I am using is Netbeans 8.2, glassfish version 4.1, java ee version: Java EE 7 Web

Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: The message you posted states _"See the server log for details"_, so update your question with the associated message(s) in the GlassFish server log. Without that information your question cannot be answered, since there are many possible reasons for deployment to fail.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I checked server logs and this message is shown when i run the application :                                                                                         Exception while deploying the app [realestate] : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource Error Code: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error, I hope this solution will help the other programmers too:
I changed the SQL connector version from 8.0.2 to 5.1.49.

Also, I download another version of MySQL workbench => 6.3 CE.

I also uninstall my NetBeans version 8.2 and download 8.1

This combination solved my problem.